# Emacs: problems with yasnippet inserting spaces in code-snippet

Tags: html, emacs, code-snippets

I have a problem with yasnippet and Emacs 23.4.1 on W7-64. I write a blog and having run into difficulties with the Wordpress visual editor I am going to see whether it might be easier to simply compose everything in HTML and paste it directly into Wordpress' HTML editor. Accordingly using the rather impressive yasnippet I created the following:

```
#contributor : blogger
#name : blog picture link
# --
<a href="http://verylongwebsitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/${1:mm}/${2:folder}/fig${3:x}_l.png"><img class="alignnone" title="fig$3" src="http://verylongwebsitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/$1/$2/fig$3_m.png" alt="${5:alttext}" width="${6:700}" height="${7:500}" /></a>$0
```

to enter long and fiddly links like the one below, in html-mode:

The problem is that at some point during the process of entering the
snippet it goes funny, like this:

[image: misbehaving yasnippet]

If you look you can see that yasnippet has inserted many spaces on each line, causing much ugliness and a broken link. Because of the way that the words are sort of aligned I suspect that it's something to do with the interaction between yasnippet and tab settings, but despite a bit of scratching around I can't resolve the problem.

Can anybody suggest what might be causing this?

Comment: Does it help to add the line `# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line 'fixed))` to the snippet as suggested in the answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069537/yasnippets-with-ending-the-line-after-0-acts-strange-when-used-with-auctex?

Comment: Thank you for the suggesstion. I tried both in separate configurations but neither seem to have any effect.

Comment: Have I stumped the communal intelligence of Stack Overflow?! I feel an odd sense of pride :-)

Comment: It may simply be that the experts concerning this issue do not hang out at SO. Thus, you could try some yasnippet mailig list. Make sure to post any solution here too though.

Comment: Better report this as a bug at https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues, be sure to include the yasnippet version you are using though. I would first try the latest HEAD from the git repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much messing around I have found that the problem was (most likely) an issue with one of Emacs' fill modes interacting with `yasnippet` in an odd way. Specifically I had it set to 'Fill' in HTML mode and what I apparently needed was 'Wrap'. My crude solution was to create a keyboard macro to switch modes and assign that to a shortcut key in my `.emacs` file as follows:

```
(fset 'my-html-fill-setup
   [?\M-x ?a ?u ?t ?o ?- ?f ?i ?l ?l ?- ?m ?o ?d ?e return ?\M-x ?v ?i ?s ?u ?a ?l ?- ?l ?i ?n ?e ?- ?m ?o ?d ?e return])

(global-set-key "\C-x\C-k1" 'my-html-fill-setup)
```

Apologies for any confusion caused. Incidentally, after managing to reinstall `yasnippet` I am loving it and find it very useful for all kinds of things.

Answer (score 3):

For me, what fixed it was disabling indentation within Yasnippet.

```
(setq yas-indent-line (quote none))
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, using latest yasnippet from github.

```
# key : entry
# contributor : blogger
# name : blog picture link
# --
<a href="http://verylongwebsitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/${1:mm}/${2:folder}/fig${3:x}_l.png">
  <img class="alignnone"
   title="fig$3"
   src="http://verylongwebsitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/$1/$2/fig$3_m.png"
   alt="${5:alttext}"
   width="${6:700}"
   height="${7:500}"/>
</a>
$0
```

Comment: Thank you for this and apologies for the delay. One cause is that I have not been well, the other is that I managed somehow to fubar my yasnippet installation and have not been able to get it running again. I appreciate the suggestion; I have never tried to install anything from github before - I presume it's just a download. I will go and take a look.