# Indent under the previous line

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

This is my snippent:

```
foo ($1)
$0
```

Where I activate it with indent and touch 'arg<Tab>bar' I want like this:

```
  foo (x)
  bar
```

But I got this:

```
  foo (x)
bar
```

My yas-indent-line is fixed. Emacs 24.2.1 Yasnippet 0.8.0 (20130218)

Comment: Does it help if you add `# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line 'fixed))` or `# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line t))` to the snippet? What version of Emacs and YASnippet are you using? In which mode do you expand the snippet? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8069537/789593

Comment: I expand the snippet in html-mode.

Comment: It will be hard to say what the problem is unless you answer the other questions.

Comment: `# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line 'fixed))` was in my first snippet and it looks like it and second doesn't help.

Comment: The monkeypatch of `yas--indent-according-to-mode` with `(sit-for 1)` doesn't work also.

Comment: But if a second line is `$0%$>` than all is ok besides unnecessary `%`

Comment: It's all. It's work if second line is `$0&#96;()&#96;$>.

Comment: It's work if second line is ``$0`()`$>`` with `# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line 'fixed))`. Thanks everybody

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is functional snippet:

```
# key: snip
# name: foo
# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line t))
# --
foo ($1)
$0`()`$>
```